# OneDrive invite people to folder not available

Tags: onedrive

Today I was trying to share a OneDrive folder and was not able to find the "invite friends" feature.

I must share the folder exclusively with people authenticated with a Microsoft Account instead of creating a public url.

I can still see some folders I share with the friend list there, but if I remove the sharing, I cannot set up it back again.

Is there any change in the way sharing works in OneDrive?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click on a folder, the first item in the dropdown should be "Share". Just follow this flow.